# Add a link from Meta /review to its main /review

Tags: feature-request, review, hyperlinks

On a [main site’s `/review`](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review), there is a link to the `/review` of its Meta site:

> [Meta Reviews](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/review)
>   Visit the review queues on Music Fans Meta Stack Exchange.

On a [Meta site’s `/review`](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/review), such a link to the main site’s `/review` is missing.

**Proposal:** Add a link from Meta `/review` to its main `/review`.

Comment: I don't see the point in this. There's a link from the main review page to the meta review page to increase the awareness of the meta review page, but if you're at the meta review page, you've got to be aware of the main review page, surely? Just because there's a link in one direction doesn't mean there *needs* to be a link the other direction?

Comment: @grgarside: Awareness is *one* goal, but not the only one. -- When reviewing on Meta and everything’s done, an easy and fast way to access the review of the main site is helpful - you’re still in review mood! -- Besides that: consistency (I *expected* to find this link there, for several times). -- And regarding awareness: following your logic, you could argue that a link from main to Meta review is not needed because those users that *review* certainly are aware that Meta sites exist.

Comment: The community would benefit greatly from something as minor as this. I can't count how many times I've wanted to switch from meta to main and having to go "the long way" ended up killing my editing mood.