# Reviews <--> Meta Reviews

Tags: discussion, review

How come there is a link from Reviews on the main site to Meta Reviews, but not one from Meta Reviews to Reviews?

It doesn't matter, I just wonder why.

Comment: Related: [Add a link from Meta /review to its main /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251265/349538)

Answer (score 10):

More people visit whatever the main site is vs its meta.

We saw a number of cases where meta review tasks were getting neglected, so the link from the main site's /review section is just another signal that a) meta exists; b) it may need attention. This generally isn't an issue the other way around.

Comment: i was thinking it might encourage Meta-rites to visit the main site more often

Comment: @JonMarkPerry That's not really an issue on most child metas. :)

Comment: my first concern was that i am always using the browser 'back' button

Comment: I think it would be nice to have a link from the Meta reviews to the main site reviews. There isn't usually much to review on Meta, and when I'm done reviewing the little there is to review there I would like to review on the main site.