# Add "Main site reviews" button in meta sites queue

Tags: feature-request, review, design, per-site-meta

Main sites have button to open meta site queue.

> [image]

But meta's queue page doesn't have button to go to main site queue.

> [image]

Could you add it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this request before but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't see a good reason for this. Certainly there's no disadvantage, but in most cases, I just don't think it's necessary. Meta sites (at least for most sites) have very few reviews, so it's not a page which people check regularly.

Comment: Related: [Reviews <--> Meta Reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285160/295232)